# BIOS protection in Linux

Tags: linux, root, bios

Would like to check a few things:

1. Does Linux machines use a BIOS at all? As I have read up that the Linux kernel directly drives the hardware, hence BIOS locking to a Linux machine will not work at all.
2. If given the scenario where the Linux machines does use a BIOS, am I able to lock it using a password and prevent it other users from modifying it. (Not sure if the root account is still able to bypass the BIOS password lock, or if the root account is being used to lock the BIOS in the first place)
3. If the root account is not able to bypass the BIOS password lock, can I still modify the BIOS settings after boot as everything on a Linux machine is a file? So theoretically I can find the correct file and modify it?

Sorry for the weird and non-sensical questions! Just really confused at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Linux kernel needs BIOS just like every other desktop OS. I'm not sure what you mean by *"BIOS locking to a Linux machine will not work at all"*.
2. Linux and BIOS have zero relationships to each other. You set your BIOS password in BIOS. If people have a physical access to your device, they can simply reboot your system and get into BIOS regardless of any protections enabled in Linux. I've not heard of a possibility of setting BIOS passwords outside of BIOS. UEFI BIOS implementations are wildly different and I'm even sure they provide this feature. I have never seen it under Windows either, i.e. there are no Windows tools to set BIOS passwords.
3. The root account cannot bypass the BIOS password lock, see point 2. Not everything in Linux is a file, this is a very old myth. There are tons of programming interfaces in Linux which operate only via API calls and nothing else.

Yes, you're confused because you believe Linux is a special OS which magically can access BIOS directly. That's not the case. Linux has built-in tools to modify EUFI variables but BIOS password is not one of them.

If you are part of a a larger organization, BIOS passwords can be managed remotely via

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Management_Engine
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Platform_Security_Processor

Comment: "I've not heard of a possibility of setting BIOS passwords outside of BIOS." Some vendors provide enterprise deployment support tools for (some of) their systems, which may be able to do this. Such tools used to be mostly DOS or FreeDOS-based, but seem now increasingly to be based on various live Linux set-ups. Unfortunately the tools and their documentation can be hard to find and sparse, assuming that your vendor even provides them.